# Replacing part of column names in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns named for years and months in the format 2000-01, 2000-02, 2000-03 etc.  I would like to replace the month with the quarter:

```
## q1 = -01,-02,-03
## q2 = -04, -05, -06
## q3 = -07, -08, -09
## q4 = -10, -11, -12
```

The desired result is column names in the form 2000q1 for each month.
Here is what I did.  This resulted in the desired output, but seems very tedious to do for all 12 months.  Does anyone know any more efficient way to do this?

```
import re
df = df.rename(columns = {col: re.sub('01', 'q1', col) for col in df.columns})
df = df.rename(columns = {col: re.sub('02', 'q1', col) for col in df.columns})
```

... and so on

Thanks,
Go Deacs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with column names as follows:

```
df.columns
# Index([u'2000-01', u'2000-02', u'2000-03', u'2000-04', u'2000-05', u'2000-06',
#        u'2000-07', u'2000-08', u'2000-09', u'2000-10', u'2000-11', u'2000-12'],
#       dtype='object')
```

You can do something like this (split the column names into year and month and convert month to quarter by a modulo division:

```
df.columns = [year + "q" + str((int(month) - 1) // 3 + 1) for year, month in df.columns.str.split("-")]

df.columns
# Index([u'2000q1', u'2000q1', u'2000q1', u'2000q2', u'2000q2', u'2000q2',
#        u'2000q3', u'2000q3', u'2000q3', u'2000q4', u'2000q4', u'2000q4'],
#       dtype='object')
```

---

Or another option:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_period("Q")

df.columns
# PeriodIndex(['2000Q1', '2000Q1', '2000Q1', '2000Q2', '2000Q2', '2000Q2',
#              '2000Q3', '2000Q3', '2000Q3', '2000Q4', '2000Q4', '2000Q4'],
#             dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```